# JS error when executing electron app with native module on other computer

Tags: reactjs, opencv, electron

I am using [opencv4nodejs](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs) (a native module) in my electron app.

When I package my app and try to run it on another computer I am getting following error:

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: dlopen(/var/folders/7m/klqbsvis2iqg_mb_pdvv79fhO000gn/
T/.app.repeato.uuz70R, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/
libopency_core.3.4.dylib
 Referenced from: /var/folders/7m/kiqbsvis2iqg_mb_pdvv79fhOG00gn/
Tf.app.repeato.uuz70R
 Reason: image not found
  at process.module.(anonymous function) (as dlopen} (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
  at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjsfosder.js:740:18)
  at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:180:18)
  at Module.load (internal{modules/cjsfoader.js:620:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559:12)
  at Function.Madule._load {internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:3)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Repeato.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js:17:8)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Applications/Repeato.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/lib/cv.js:28:3)
```

Any ideas what's wrong?
I found a very [similar issue on github](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2738), but not sure if it really is

EDIT

I am building with electron-builder and building with the command `npm run dist`. 
Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Repeato",
  "description": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": {
    "name": "...",
    "email": "..."
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "app.myapp",
    "productName": "Repeato",
    "mac": {
      "category": "public.app-category.developer-tools"
    },
    "files": [
      "!minicap/*",
      "!minitouch/*"
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      "minicap/**",
      "minitouch/**"
    ],
    "directories": {}
  },
  "scripts": {
    "electron-rebuild": "electron-rebuild -w opencv4nodejs",
    "clean": "rm -rf node_modules",
    "reinstall": "npm run clean && npm install",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run start-dev\" \"npm run start-electron\"",
    "start-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server",
    "start-electron": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development electron index",
    "build": "npm run dist && npm run build-all",
    "bundle": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack  --config webpack.production.config.js",
    "build-all": "build -lmw",
    "test": "ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=true ./node_modules/.bin/electron ./node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "prettier": "prettier --write app/**/*.js",
    "prettier:staged": "pretty-quick --staged",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "pack": "npm run bundle && electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "npm run bundle && electron-builder"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "android",
    "UI testing"
  ],
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^1.10.5",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid": "^1.10.5",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-grid-material-ui": "^1.10.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "fix-path": "^2.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^3.10.0",
    "node-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "opencv4nodejs": "^4.11.0",
    "react-image-crop": "^6.0.18",
    "react-sizeme": "^2.5.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.54",
    "ws": "^6.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "electron": "^3.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^20.28.4",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "^2.2.4",
    "electron-prebuilt-compile": "^3.0.10",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.8.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "mobx": "^4.8.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^6.0.3",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.10.0",
    "react": "^16.5.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.6.3",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.27.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

And my webpack.production.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: ['babel-polyfill', './app/index'],
    worker: ['babel-polyfill', './app/worker.js']
  },
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static'),
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.node$/,
        use: 'node-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_compontents)/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: 'index.html', inject: false }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    })
  ],
  target: 'electron-renderer'
}
```

Comment: Can you post how you ran the project?

Comment: Native modules are mostly platform specific, sometimes OS version matters too. So you either include the correctly built native module in your packaged app for that other computer, or your setup should include building the module from source on that computer. Please make sure you checked.

Comment: @Jacob added some information

Comment: Are you trying to autobuild your app on windows which is failing?

Comment: Could it be, that your module is part of the dev dependencies?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no I am running everything on mac.

Comment: @wawa no it's not

Answer (score 2):

You have to bundle your app with the shared object libraries of OpenCV. The opencv4nodejs contains external references to the *libopency_core.3.4.dylib* dynamic library of your opencv installation. You have it on you machine but it is not installed correctly on the machine where you have the issue. You have to ship the shared object libraries with the package and link correctly against them.

One of the reasons may be that electron-builder packs the whole app folder into an *asar* archive file completely. This makes the library unavailavble for loading. Put `"asar": false` into *package.json* file to prevent this and keep everything in folder:

```
"build": {
    "asar": false,
    ...
```

Another possible reason is that you don't link the library to the target. Set a relative path in *binding.gyp* for opencv4nodejs:

```
"link_settings": {
    "libraries": [
        "-Wl,-rpath,@loader_path/../../../opencv-build/opencv/build/lib"
    ],
},
```

I think there is no way to make opencv4nodejs to load shared library from archive. If you want asar try `asarUnpack` the libraries.

```
"build": {
    "asarUnpack": [
        ...
    ]
    ...
```